# Content gets cut off on HTTP request with GZIP compression (only in browser)

Tags: http, browser, haskell, gzip

I'm developing a web application in Haskell using the Yesod web framework (altough I think that this problem is not related to Haskell and/or Yesod, I'm just mentioning this for completeness). I'm using the Warp server in order to serve request and I'm experiencing a strange problem when accessing sites using Chromium/Firefox (but not Opera) involving GZIP compression.

I have a site set up which returns only `Hello world!`.

- If I fetch the site using `netcat` and I set `Accept-Encoding` to `gzip`, I get the correct result. That means I can decompress the data I receive and it correctly decompresses to `Hello world!`.
- If I want to look at the site using Chromium or Firefox, all I get is `H` (the rest of the content is cut off). I verified that the `Content-Length` and `Content-Encoding` headers are set correctly by the server.

Here is the code I use to send the `Hello world!` string:

```
getRootR = return $ RepPlain $ toContent ("Hello world!" :: ByteString)
```

I'm calling Warp with the standard `run` function:

```
withWebApp $ Warp.run 3000
```

This is the request I'm sending with `netcat`, with which it works:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,
```

And the result of decompressing the output of netcat:

```
$ nc --idle-timeout=1 localhost 3000 < test | tail -n1 | gunzip
nc: using stream socket
Hello world!
```

And one more thing: If I sniff the traffic using Wireshark the packets show up as HTTP traffic, but Wireshark tells me `(text/plain)Continuation or non-HTTP traffic`. The packet looks fine to me tough.

So for some reason, it just won't work in Chromium or Firefox and I can't figure out why. Can anybody help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just a blind shot, what happens when you `GET http://foo.bar/ HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: You mean if I try it with HTTP 1.1 instead of HTTP 1.0 through netcat? I get the same result.

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is an issue with the warp gzip layer. All this stuff is very new and under development. I'd contact the warp guys (msnoyman in particular) directly, and turn off gzip compression until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely reason is the Content-Length is not set properly, i.e. the server reports the size of the original content as opposed to the size of the compressed data.
As sclv states above, this must be a bug in the web server.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly right! The Content-Length matches the original content and not the compressed content. Obviously it worked with netcat because I just fed gunzip whatever the server sent :-). Now I just have to report this.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is *not* a bug in Warp, but in wai-extra. Just be sure that if you're suffering from this issue that you upgrade wai-extra; new versions of Warp will not affect this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is a bug in wai-extra. It seems that the correct action should be to remove an Content-Length headers when using gzip, so that Warp will automatically serve chunked transfer encoding. I'll release a patch later today hopefully.